# “unresolved variable or type google” for google.script

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, autocomplete, webstorm, code-inspection

Using Google Apps Script, WebStorm is telling me that google is unresolved. Which library should I add in the Languages & Frameworks to resolve it?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should use [@types/google.script.client-side](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/google.script.client-side)
[image]